# Search in SharePoint page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, html

I have a SharePoint page with content editor that hold a list of links.

```
Link1
Link2
Link3
```

I want to search for Link1 using java script to get the physical URL of Link1

Any idea would be helpful ?

Comment: Is there any class or ID applied on your Link1, Link2 and Link3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be simple.

Lets say your links contains following html in your page.

```
<a href="http://www.somthing1.com" id="link1" >Link1</a>
<a href="http://www.somthing2.com" id="link2" >Link2</a>
<a href="http://www.somthing3.com" id="link3" >Link3</a>
```

Below Javascript should work fine for you.

```
<script>
var link1HTML = document.getElementById('link1').innerHTML;
if(link1HTML == "Link1")
{
    var link1URL = document.getElementById('link1').href;
    alert(link1URL);
}
</script>
```

Make sure you load above JavaScript after your links on the page.

Hope that helps.